# Samba users with the same permissions, only one can login

Tags: ubuntu, samba

Fresh install of Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Samba.  The share is setup as follows:

```
[share]
    comment = My Share
    path = /srv/samba/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = no
    create mask = 2775
    directory mask = 0775
    write list = @group1
```

The directory /srv/samba/share has permissions 777 and is owned by user1:group1.

I have user2 and user3, both of whom have group1 as their primary group.

groups user2 
user2 : group1

groups user3 
user3 : group1

The problem I'm having is that user1 & user2 can access the share just fine, but not user3 (connecting from Windows 7). user3 can see the share, but can't get past the login prompt.  user3 can ssh into the same server no problem. The /var/log/samba/smbd.log doesn't show anything related to this.  I'm at a loss because I'm not really where to look to troubleshoot this further.  Help!

Comment: What OS are other users connecting from? Have you tried resetting user3's Samba password? (use `smbpasswd`, Samba has a separate database.)

Comment: That was the problem.  I didn't realize there was an smbpasswd.  The thing that threw me off is that I never used smbpasswd for user1 & user2 so I'm still confused.  But setting smbpasswd fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the Unix and Samba account databases have different passwords for `user3`, or that Samba is lacking the account completely. Use `smbpasswd` to fix it.

You can enable `pam_smbpasswd.so` in PAM, which will automatically update the Samba account every time the user logs in locally or over SSH. *(Of course, won't work with public-key logins.)*